# Numpy flatten dimension function

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to Python and am trying to extract RGB-encoded pixel labels from a numpy array. For example:

```
image.shape
>> (256, 256, 3)
```

to be converted to:

```
image.shape
>> (256, 256, 1)
```

based on a custom function. In Javascript such a function would be (the exact RGB encoding is, of course, irrelevant - but being able to use a custom function is relevant):

```
RGBtoVal = ([r,g,b])=>{
   r = Math.floor(r*9/255);
   g = Math.floor(g*9/255);
   b = Math.floor(b*9/255);
   if (r>0) return r+18;
   if (g>0) return r+9;
   return b;
}
```

I understand that `reshape` and `squeeze` are helpful in reducing the dimensionality but without a function. Also, is a numpy matrix of shape (256,256,1) the same as (256,256)?

Comment: "Also, is a numpy matrix of shape (256,256,1) the same as (256,256)? " No. (256,256,1) is a 3D matrix while (256,256) is a 2D matrix

Comment: A (256,256,1) can be reshaped to (256,256) (and vv).  But to reduce the (256,256,3) to either, you have to somehow calculate a new b/w value from the 3 rgb values (for each pixel).  You should be able to do that with `numpy` whole array methods.

Comment: As the third dimension lacks depth, "removing" it would just update bookkeeping though right? It wouldn't actually move/delete data?

Comment: shape `(256, 256, 3)` means image `256x256` with pixels which have 3 values `R`, `G`, `B` .  Shape `(256, 256, 1)` means image `256x256` in `grayscale` which has only one value for every pixel - and probalby it is not what you need. You need rather `r = image[:,:,0] *9 / 255`

Comment: BTW: numpy let you make calculations for all pixels at once without `for`-loop - for example `r = image[:,:,0] *9 / 255` will calculate for all `R` in all pixels. Don't try to extract single pixel because it will take longer then calculate for all pixels at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `numpy` you can work with vectors and you don't have to work with every pixel separatelly.

In examples I use image `4x4` with values `(1,1,1)`

```
import numpy as np

image = np.ones([4,4,3])  # image 4x4 with RGB (3 values)

print(image.shape) # (4, 4, 3)

R = image[:,:,0]  # all R values
G = image[:,:,1]  # all G values
B = image[:,:,2]  # all B values

print(R.shape) # (4, 4)
print(G.shape) # (4, 4)
print(B.shape) # (4, 4)

R = R * 9/255
G = R * 9/255
B = B * 9/255

R[ R > 0 ] += 18
G[ G > 0 ] += 9

print(R)
print(G)
print(B)

print(image)
```

or you can even use `* 9/255` before you split to `R,G,B`

```
import numpy as np

image = np.ones([4,4,3])

print(image.shape)

image = image * 9/255

R = image[:,:,0]
G = image[:,:,1]
B = image[:,:,2]

R[ R > 0 ] += 18
G[ G > 0 ] += 9

print(R)
print(G)
print(B)

print(image)
```

If you want to do this in more traditional way then use [numpy.apply_along_axis(func, axis, arr)](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) with axis `2`

```
import numpy as np

# --- fuctions ---

def function(rgb):
    #rgb = rgb * 9/255
    r, g, b = rgb

    r = r * 9/255
    g = g * 9/255
    b = b * 9/255

    if r > 0:
        r += 18
    if g > 0 :
        g += 9 

    return [r,g,b]

# --- main ---

image = np.ones([4,4,3])

print(image.shape)

image = np.apply_along_axis(function, 2, image)

print(image[:,:,0])  # R
print(image[:,:,1])  # G
print(image[:,:,2])  # B

print(image)
```

Comment: Thank you! I just needed to combine RGB values so I added the resulting arrays --- image = r+g+b. I attempted apply_along_axis and it was taking too long to run, I believe this is because it skips over optimizations that are used for standard numpy functions.

Answer (score 1):

> being able to use a custom function is relevant

Converting a three-channel image into a single-channel image through a function is straightforward. For example:

```py
In [96]: import numpy as np

In [97]: from skimage import data

In [98]: image = data.astronaut()

In [99]: def f(img):
    ...:     r, g, b = map(np.transpose, img.T)
    ...:     return np.floor(r*9/255) + np.sqrt(g) + np.cos(b)

In [100]: x = f(image)

In [101]: image.shape
Out[101]: (512, 512, 3)

In [102]: x.shape
Out[102]: (512, 512)
```

> is a numpy matrix of shape (256,256,1) the same as (256,256)?

No. They are arrays of different shapes.

```py
In [103]: y = x[:, :, None]

In [104]: y.shape
Out[104]: (512, 512, 1)

In [105]: x[0, 0]    
Out[105]: 13.1044921875

In [106]: y[0, 0]
Out[106]: array([13.10449219])

In [107]: y[0, 0, 0]
Out[107]: 13.1044921875
```

The content of `x` and `y` is the same but `x` is two-dimensional whereas `y` is three-dimensional. It is worth noticing that indexing a three-dimensional array with just two indices yields a one-dimensional array of one element rather than a float value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What is the benefit of np.transpose (line 99.1) and img.T of the map function? Coming from javascript I'm less clear as to how 'map' operates in Python.

Comment: `r, g, b = map(np.transpose, img.T)` is compact a way of splitting the RGB image into its chromatic bands. It is equivalent to `r = img[:, :, 0]`, `g = img[:, :, 1]` and `b = img[:, :, 2]`.